# Validar nombre y apellido usando PHP

Tags: php, regex

Necesito validar 2 campos de mi formulario, `$nombre` y `$apellidos`.

He estado probando con este código pero no cumple con todas las condiciones que quiero aplicar a la validación, entre ellas los espacios en blanco comunes en nombres y apellidos:

```
if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z'-]+$/",$nombre)) {
    echo "El nombre tiene caracteres inválidos";
}
```

Lo que necesito es lo siguiente (El nombre y apellidos usarán la misma validación excepto en longitud):

- Solo debe tener caracteres a-z A-Z (incluida la letra **Ñ** y **espacios**).
- Un mínimo de 3 caracteres (sin contar con espacios)
- Un máximo de 18 caracteres en el nombre y 36 en los apellidos.

Mi código:

```
// Validar nombre
if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z'-]+$/",$nombre)) {
    array_push($errors, "El nombre contiene caracteres inválidos.");
} else if (strlen($firstname) > 18) {
    array_push($errors, "El nombre solo puede contener hasta 18 caracteres.");
} else if (strlen($firstname) < 3) {
    array_push($errors, "El nombre debe tener al menos 3 caracteres.");
}


// Validar apellidos
if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z'-]+$/",$apellidos)) {
    array_push($errors, "Los apellidos contienen caracteres inválidos.");
} else if (strlen($lastname) > 36) {
    array_push($errors, "Los apellidos solo pueden contener hasta 36 caracteres.");
} else if (strlen($lastname) < 3) {
    array_push($errors, "Los apellidos debe tener al menos 3 caracteres.");
}
```

Como pueden ver le falta el filtro de ESPACIOS y la letra Ñ. En cuanto a longitud ya lo tengo, solo que faltaría el mínimo de 3 caracteres pero contando solo letras y no espacios para que esto sea inválido: `"      "`

> **Nota:** `array_push($errors, "Mensaje de error.");` `$errors` es un array que almacena todos los errores y posteriormente los muestra en
>   el formulario.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Creo que lo tengo:

El nombre: `/^(?=.{3,18}$)[a-zñA-ZÑ](\s?[a-zñA-ZÑ])*$/`

- `(?=.{3,18}$)`-> te comprueba la longitud, si tiene mas de 3 y menos de 18 caracteres
- `[a-zñA-ZÑ]`-> mira la primera palabra y si cumple la norma de ser solo Alfabetica con `ñ` incluio
- `(\s?[a-zñA-ZÑ])`-> en caso de que haya un espacio, le indico que habra otra palabra

El apellido sera igual, pero indicamos que el máximo son 36 caracteres: `^(?=.{3,36}$)[a-zñA-ZÑ](\s?[a-zñA-ZÑ])*$`.

Claramente no te hará coincidencia sin hay 3 espacios al principio. Espero que te sirva.

Comment: He probado varios nombres y ninguna funciona entre ellos "pablo". Este es mi código: `if (!preg_match("^(?=.{3,18}$)[a-zñA-ZÑ](\s?[a-zñA-ZÑ])*$",$firstname)) {
        array_push($errors, "El nombre contiene caracteres inválidos.");
    }`

Comment: creo que tienes algún error de syntaxis `preg_match('/^(?=.{3,18}$)[a-zñA-ZÑ](\s?[a-zñA-ZÑ])*$/', $firstname)`

Comment: Sí solo eran las barras. Si quieres ponlas para que nadie se equivoque. Gracias y saludos.

Comment: esta muy bien lo malo es que no creo poder usar esta web `O'keefe` =(

Answer (score 2):

Intenta con este ejemplo, aqui permito todos los caracteres que se pueden para conformar un nombre y un apellido y valido la longitud de los mismos, si quieres saber exactamente en que fallaron hasmelo saber para editar la respuesta

```
if(!preg_match("/^([A-Za-zÑñ]+[áéíóú]?[A-Za-z]*){3,18}\s+([A-Za-zÑñ]+[áéíóú]?[A-Za-z]*){3,36}$/iu", 'dariel nuñez')) {
    array_push($errors, "El formato del nombre y apellido es incorrecto");
} else {
    echo "Okey";
}
```